# How to handle intermediate dependencies with variant directories and the PDF builder?

Tags: pdf, latex, scons

I am trying to build a LaTeX document with scons where some of the sources of the PDF target are targets of other builders.  This works great until I try to combine that with variant directories.  It looks like once I add the variant directory to the SConscript call, all the built sources no longer get scanned properly into the dependency tree for the PDF target.

Am I doing something wrong in my minimal working example to setup this type of build?

```
>> scons --version
SCons by Steven Knight et al.:
    script: v2.5.1.rel_2.5.1:3735:9dc6cee5c168[MODIFIED], 2016/11/03 14:02:02, by bdbaddog on mongodog
    engine: v2.5.1.rel_2.5.1:3735:9dc6cee5c168[MODIFIED], 2016/11/03 14:02:02, by bdbaddog on mongodog
    engine path: ['/usr/lib/scons/SCons']
Copyright (c) 2001 - 2016 The SCons Foundation

>> tree  
.
├── SConstruct
└── src
    ├── document.tex
    ├── foo.in
    └── SConscript

1 directory, 4 files

>> cat SConstruct 
# SConscript('src/SConscript')                                  # <- Works
SConscript('src/SConscript', variant_dir='build', duplicate=0)  # <- Error

>> cat src/foo.in 
Bar

>> cat src/document.tex 
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{foo}
\end{document}

>> cat src/SConscript 
Command('foo.tex', 'foo.in', Copy('$TARGET', '$SOURCE'))
PDF('document.tex')

>> scons --tree=prune
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
cd build && pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -recorder document.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/nfs/msdev/users/bellockk/Development/SConsMakoTeX/SOQ/src/document.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./document.aux)

! LaTeX Error: File `foo.tex' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: tex)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.3 \input{foo}
               ^^M
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on document.log.
pdflatex returned an error, check the log file
scons: *** [build/document.pdf] Error 1
+-.
  +-SConstruct
  +-build
  | +-src/SConscript
  | +-build/document.acn
  | | +-build/document.pdf
  | |   +-src/document.tex
  | +-build/document.acr
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-build/document.alg
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-build/document.aux
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-build/document.bbl
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-build/document.bcf
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-build/document.blg
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-build/document.fls
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-build/document.glg
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-build/document.glo
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-build/document.gls
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-build/document.idx
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-build/document.ilg
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-build/document.ind
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-build/document.lof
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-build/document.log
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-build/document.lot
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-build/document.nav
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-build/document.nlg
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-build/document.nlo
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-build/document.nls
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-build/document.out
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-build/document.snm
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-build/document.synctex.gz
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-src/document.tex
  | +-build/document.toc
  | | +-[build/document.pdf]
  | +-src/foo.in
  | +-build/foo.tex
  |   +-src/foo.in
  +-src
    +-src/SConscript
    +-src/document.tex
    +-src/foo.in
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Comment: Can you try this with duplicate=1? The underlying problem is, that the LaTeX builder "cd"s into the folder of the TeX file first...

Comment: Yes, it works with duplicate=1, but I would really prefer to have this off.  I have to work with another issue with the PDF builder where if I set duplicate=1, it does not run pdflatex the correct number of times to generate the table of contents.  I'm curious as to why the "cd into the folder of the tex file" in the build command affects the dependency scanning.